# How to build chromedriver.exe on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Our project have changed chromium source code a lot, so I have to build my own chromedriver.exe for selenium.

At first, I want to figure out how to build chromium's chromedriver on Windows. Then I can find a
way to build a chromedrive for our own project.

Now I can build chromium. But  I can not build chromedriver.exe in our own project now. I need to find out what the independence of chromedriver project.  I need to figure out which projects we have modified that influence chromedirver.

Answer (score 3):

Build **chromedriver** target as mentioned below,

```
ninja -C out/Release chromedriver
```

Once it finishes you can find the executable in out/Release/chromedriver.

Comment: I just tried doing that on my linux (64-bit). It's taking quite a while? It's stuck on `log: now monitoring process activity`

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver is a Chromium project and the code lives in the Chromium repo.

You can start the research from https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/UsingGit this page, it'll walk you through the source code and building of Chromium itself.

Comment: Thanks at first! I can build chromium. But as I said before, we have changed chromium a lot, so I can not build chromedriver.exe in our project now. I need to find out what the independence of chromedriver project.  I need to figure out which projects we have modified that influence chromedirver.

Comment: The link is dead: Error 404

Answer (score 1):

A bit more explanation on how to build the chromium project on windows

Step1:
click this link :-(http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools)
check the section with heading "Windows (Cygwin and non-Cygwin)"{better to install cygwin on your machine}

Step2:
in this step we need to check out the code
go to the following link to checkout the code from SVN
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Step3:
check the below link for bulinding components 
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/component-build
after this setup is done regenerate the build files by running "gclient runhooks --force" in a cygwin/cmd window
Step4:
getting the api key and installing them
go through the following link the steps here are pretty much clear
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

Step5:
Open the chrome/chrome.sln solution file in Visual Studio and build the solution. This can take from 10 minutes to 2 hours. More likely 1 hour.

If you just want the Chromium browser, and none of the tests, you can speed up your build by right-clicking the chrome project in the solution explorer and selecting Build.
You may want to make sure this project is the Startup project (which will display as bold) by right-clicking it and selecting Set as Startup Project. 
This will make Chromium (as opposed to some random test) build and run when you press F5.

Ref:http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows

Comment: Thanks at first! I can build chromium. But as I said before, we have changed chromium a lot, so I can not build chromedriver.exe in our project now. I need to find out what the independence of chromedriver project.  I need to figure out which projects we have modified that influence chromedirver.

Comment: @super, you should able to build using `ninja -C out/Release chromedriver` as mentioned in `http://stackoverflow.com/a/22321176/1942688`.